# Creating database using fluent NHibernate

Tags: c#, vb.net, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

I am using fluent NHibernate. I want to create database by using mapping. My code is as

```
Shared Function GetConfig() As FluentConfiguration
        Return Fluently.Configure().Database(MySQLConfiguration.Standard.ConnectionString(Function(c) c.Server("localhost").Database("im").Username("root").Password("pass"))).Mappings(Function(m) m.FluentMappings.AddFromAssemblyOf(Of UserMap())())
    End Function

GetConfig().ExposeConfiguration(Function(c) New SchemaExport(c).Execute(script, export__1, justDrop)).BuildConfiguration()
```

but New SchmaExport(c) can't be compile. Error expression does not produce a value. What to I do to solve this. And will this function create database for me. or I am doing it wrong? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
    GetConfig().ExposeConfiguration(Sub(x As NHibernate.Cfg.Configuration) Dim ex As SchemaExport = New SchemaExport(x)
 ex.Execute(script, export__1, justDrop) End Sub).BuildConfiguration()
```

Answer (score 1):

```
                return Fluently.Configure()
                .Database(MsSqlConfiguration.MsSql2008.ConnectionString(_connectionString))
                .Mappings(m => m.FluentMappings.AddFromAssembly(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly()))
                .BuildSessionFactory();
```

Comment: i want to fuildconfiguration not sessionfactory. and for mysql. this works when sessionfactioy has to be created. Thanks

Comment: Youre Welcome Bro :).. Can you raise my answer.